# How to configure JaVers with OpenJPA in a Spring boot project

Tags: openjpa, javers

I'm trying to set up auditing for my project which is currently a Spring boot with Open JPA. Require help/pointers on configuring Javers for Open JPA.

I have tried configuring the project with SpringBoot annotations provided by Javers. It gives me following error -

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Session

```
    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public DialectName javersSqlDialectName() {
        Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();//.getSession();
        Dialect hibernateDialect=null;
        try {
            Object dialect =
                  org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(session.getSessionFactory(), "dialect");
            hibernateDialect = (Dialect) dialect;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Serious error");
        }

        return dialectMapper.map(hibernateDialect);
    }
```

Comment: `javers-spring-jpa` module depends on `hibernate-core`, take a look at the code https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-spring-jpa

There are a few classes that you should implement for Open JPA

Comment: Thanks Bartek, can you please help with which all classes I might have to modify